# Python Google Sheets API v4: How to do Batch Get and Batch Update Google sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google Sheets API v4:

Python Quickstart shows how to get data from a Google Spreadsheet:

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values()
         .get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

See https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python

Now, I have resolved the syntax for Batch Get:

I have tried the following but get null for 'values':

```
rangeName = ["Class Data!A2:E2","Class Data!A3:E3"]
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(
         spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=(rangeName)).execute()
for r in result['valueRanges']:
    print (r.values()[0],r.values()[1])
```

Comment: Can you post your code or snippet like authorization and the main code that uses the spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate/batchGet, and the error logs too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone finds this on Google, the answer is (like NoisyFlasher implied with that Java example, and like the OP was on the track to) to simply provide the ranges as a Python list. However, the result is a dict, not objects:

```
rangeName = ["Class Data!A2:E2","Class Data!A3:E3"]
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(
         spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=rangeName).execute()
for r in result['valueRanges']:
    print (r['values'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with python but I met same problem with java client and hope this solution will help.
I tried to load ranges only with

```
service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet
                        (spreadsheetID).execute();
```

as documentation said, but there was no results. When I found a way - to make batchGet you should specify list of ranges which you want to get from spreadsheet. Please, make a note to this **setRange()** invokaion:

```
final ArrayList<String> RANGES = new ArrayList<>();
        RANGES.add("Sheet1");
        RANGES.add("Sheet2");
BatchGetValuesResponse response = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet
                    (spreadsheetID).setRanges(RANGES).execute();
```

Comment: I have tried to transfer Java into Python syntax (see above) but without success.

Comment: I meant that probably you should set ranges by additional function - not just passing two params to get().
I think, I'll check it.

Comment: Also, here is the example of batchUpdate():
https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#example

Comment: Thanks, your ideas helped me. Basically, what I did wrong is considering the right format for the return values. Above the corrected version.